# Download enormous Base64 in Javascript

Tags: javascript, download

I have a Javascript widget that creates .wav files. After running it, a Base64 representation of the file is generated, so that the user can play it in the browser. To download it, I then put the Base64 as the href of an  element with the download attribute and programatically click it.

This all works fine and relatively quick for small files. However, if my Base64 exceeds about 2^21 characters in length (only 16 seconds of audio!), I get no download window to open.

Is there any other way I can get the download to work with files this large, without having to first upload the files elsewhere?

Edit: I'm using the latest version of Chrome. Firefox doesn't seem to have this issue.

Comment: which browser are you using?

Comment: have you considered using `Blob`?

Comment: @JaromandaX I'm using Chrome. Edited.
I wasn't aware of Blobs. How would this work with them?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL may help

Comment: if you look at documentation for [data uri](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs) it states in there that firefox has no limitation to size, which is why you see that firefox "works" - blobs should help - I've used https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/ in the past for a more seamless cross browser experience

Comment: @JaromandaX I searched a bit on Blobs, implemented them, and everything went perfectly. Thanks!